# Why transform-origin property is not working?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I have a mini-question concerning the return value of transform-origin in javascript :
I have a simple div with a transform-origin set to 0 0 via CSS and i'm trying to console.log() the div.style.transformOrigin but I get nothing, not even an error... What am I doing wrong ?

In here [link](http://webdevable.com/w3schools/jsref/prop_style_transformorigin.html#gsc.tab=0) it says "Return the transformOrigin property: object.style.transformOrigin".

That's what I'm trying to do...

```js
 let div_1 = document.querySelector('#div1');

console.log('the transform origin is : ', div_1.style.transformOrigin);
```

```css
 #div1 {
            width: 100px;
            height: 300px;
            transform-origin: 0 0;
            background-color: red;
        }
```

```html
 <div id="div1">hello</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [reliable source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) we can read that:

> The style read-only property returns the inline style of an element in the form of a CSSStyleDeclaration object that contains a list of all styles properties for that element with values assigned for the attributes that are defined in the element's inline style attribute.

Try using:

```
getComputedStyle(div_1).getPropertyValue('transform-origin')
```

`element.style` works only if you modify it directly, not on the class or id

```js
let div_1 = document.querySelector('#div1');

console.log('the transform origin is : ', getComputedStyle(div_1).getPropertyValue('transform-origin'));
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">hello</div>
```

Sidenote: w3schools isn't a reliable source of information

```js
let div_1 = document.querySelector('#div1');
div_1.style.transformOrigin = '0 0'

console.log('the transform origin is : ', div_1.style.transformOrigin);
```

```css
#div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">hello</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Konrad Linkowski thx for the help. Yes I know I can get the property value via getComputedStyle() method... I just don't understand why `object.style.transformOrigin` doesn't work. Why in the article I mentioned it says "to return the transformOrigin property use `object.style.transformOrigin`"...

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "element.style only works if you modify it directly, not on the class or id" ?

Comment: Updated the question with the second example. And as I said, don't rely on w3schools

Comment: of course !! Thx @Konrad Linkowski :)